# State objects are doubling when back and forth button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The state object is doubling every time when the `back` and `next` button is pressed on the browser. Due to this problem, the browser become extremely slow.

```
$(function(){
    $('.button').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var nextUrl = 'page1.html';
        history.pushState({url: nextUrl}, "", nextUrl);
        $('body').load(nextUrl);
    });
    history.replaceState({url: window.location.href}, '', '');

    $(window).on('popstate', function(e){
        var state = e.originalEvent.state;
        if(state){
            url = state.url;
            console.log(state);
        }
        $('body').load(url);
    });     
});
</script>


<a class="button" href="#">Click me</a>
```

This is what it looks like in Google Chrome console when clicking the `back` and `next` button on the browser.

```
Object {url: "http://localhost/history/index.html"} index.html:22
Object {url: "page1.html"} index.html:22
Object {url: "page1.html"} VM3222:15
Object {url: "http://localhost/history/index.html"} index.html:22
Object {url: "http://localhost/history/index.html"} VM3222:15
Object {url: "page1.html"} index.html:22
Object {url: "page1.html"} VM3222:15
Object {url: "page1.html"} VM3226:15
Object {url: "page1.html"} VM3227:15
Object {url: "http://localhost/history/index.html"} index.html:22
Object {url: "http://localhost/history/index.html"} VM3222:15
Object {url: "http://localhost/history/index.html"} VM3226:15
Object {url: "http://localhost/history/index.html"} VM3227:15
Object {url: "page1.html"} index.html:22
Object {url: "page1.html"} VM3222:15
Object {url: "page1.html"} VM3226:15
Object {url: "page1.html"} VM3227:15
Object {url: "page1.html"} VM3268:15
Object {url: "page1.html"} VM3269:15
Object {url: "page1.html"} VM3270:15
Object {url: "page1.html"} VM3271:15
```

In FireFox, the console look like this:
[image]

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: It will go to page1.html when the button is clicked, and when the back button is clicked, it will go back to index.html. That's it. But I noticed that if I keep click the back and forward button multiple times, which It will swap from index.html to page1.html and back to index.html. The state object is doubled.

Comment: Looks like popstate is not standard:  "Chrome and Safari always emit a popstate event on page load, but Firefox doesn't." see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate

Comment: I think the way you implemented replaceState is you need to change it . Probably need to remove it.

Comment: I've removed replaceState but the state is still doubling